# html sometimes not displayed in email

Tags: html, email, jakarta-mail

I have written a java code to send html emails. When I send the emails to a group of recipients at once, the email is displayed as it should be. Here's the code for the same:

```
String content="<html><p><h1>This is my first java mail with an image but there is a difference.</h1></p><p><img src=\"http://***/ImageLoader2.php\"></p></html>";
m.setSubject(subject);
m.setContent(content,"text/html");

InternetAddress[] toAdd=new InternetAddress[to.length];

    for(int i=0;i<to.length;i++)
        toAdd[i]=new InternetAddress(to[i]);

    for (InternetAddress toAdd1 : toAdd)
                m.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAdd1);
            Transport t=s.getTransport("smtp");
            t.connect(host, user, pass);
            t.sendMessage(m, m.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println("MESAAGES SENT");
    t.close();
```

And here's the output:

[image: first]

Now here's the code where I send the emails individually:

```
m.setSubject(subject);
Transport t=s.getTransport("smtp");
    t.connect(host, user, pass);

            for(int i=0;i<to.length;i++){
                content="<html><p><h1>This is my first java mail with an image but there is a difference.</h1></p><p><img src=\"http://***/ImageLoader2.php?uid="+to[i]+"\"></p></html>";
                InternetAddress toAdd=new InternetAddress(to[i]);
                m.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAdd);
                m.setContent(content,"text/html");
                t.sendMessage(m, m.getAllRecipients());
            }           

            System.out.println("MESAAGES SENT");
    t.close();
        }
```

And here's the output for this code:

[image: second]

Why is this happening? I know css often breaks on web mail systems but I am not using any. Google wasn't of any help either.

Thanks

**EDIT**

In the broken mail, these fields are missing in the headers:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Other than that, there's no other signifiacnt difference.

**EDIT**

I also tried setting the headers using `m.setHeader()` but that didn't work.

Comment: Additionally, For windows live mail, emails are displayed correctly when I use either method

Comment: Can you highlight differences in the message sources between a working and a broken example?

Comment: Gmail has an option to see the original content by click on the down arrow and choosing `Show original`. Do that for both and compare. It's possible that latter does not have a valid html or content type is not set correctly.

Comment: @tripleee, please take a look at the edit

Comment: @StepanGrigoryan You are right, the broken email is missing headers. But why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're reusing the same MimeMessage object for each recipient.  Create a new MimeMessage object each time and I suspect it will work better.

Comment: That works! But why? Why are the content-type headers deleted everytime I reusing the object? Is there a problem with my implementation or is it something to do with the implementation of MIME objects itslef? I also tried resetting the headers everytime but that didn't work either

Comment: I'm not sure why the original version fails; that would require more debugging.  I think it's related to the fact that saveChanges isn't being called.  Normally it's called implicitly when you do the send, but that only happens the first time.